# Swing JPopupMenu: grey area overlapping

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

Customers say that they have problem with UI. Sometimes when they open popup menu and after it disappear grey area did not disappear. We use Swing and grey rectangle shown at popup place (`JPopupMenu`).

[image: Gray area]

I can't reproduce that problem. Where I can read about that?

Comment: Are there any AWT components in the GUI at all?  Are all GUI updates done on the EDT?

Comment: To further clarify @AndrewThompson comments: mixing of lightweight/heavyweight and menus is tackled in [the menu tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), and [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) might be an interesting article as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- not possible mixing AWT PopupMenu with any Swing JComponent directly and vice versa, reason misses methods for mixing `AWT PopupMenu` with Swing Whatever and vice versa (aaaach why isn't the same implementations for rest of AWT and Swing J/Component too)
- out of EDT hasn't nothing to do with image that you posted here, because both Popup and JPopup has implemented rellated methods from MOUSE_RIGHT_CLICK in the API correctly, only AWT PopupMenu will be displayed only on first monitor even container could be placed on 2nd or 3rd monitor, AFAIK fixed only for Swing JPopupMenu

if isn't there any event(s) in EDT for example after 30seconds EDT returns false, J/Popup works in all cases for Java6_019 or 22

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class IsThereEDT {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private AccurateScheduledRunnable periodic;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> periodicMonitor;
    private int taskPeriod = 30;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    private Date dateRun;
    private JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Frame 1");
    private Frame frame2 = new Frame("Frame 2");
    private PopupMenu popup1 = new PopupMenu();

    public IsThereEDT() {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        periodic = new AccurateScheduledRunnable() {

            private final int ALLOWED_TARDINESS = 200;
            private int countRun = 0;
            private int countCalled = 0;
            private int maxCalled = 10;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                countCalled++;
                if (countCalled < maxCalled) {
                    if (countCalled % 3 == 0) {
                        /*if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        //some stuff
                        }
                        });
                        } else {
                        try {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        //some stuff
                        }
                        });
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(IsThereEDT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(IsThereEDT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        }*/
                        /*SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Push a new event to EDT");
                        frame1.repaint();
                        isThereReallyEDT();
                        }
                        });*/
                    } else {
                        if (this.getExecutionTime() < ALLOWED_TARDINESS) {
                            countRun++;
                            isThereReallyEDT(); // non on EDT
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Terminating this madness");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        };
        periodicMonitor = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodic, 0, taskPeriod, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        periodic.setThreadMonitor(periodicMonitor);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                isThereReallyEDT();
                Label label1 = new Label("Hello in frame 1");

                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("item" + i);
                    popup1.add(menuItem);
                }
                label1.add(popup1);
                frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame1.add(label1);
                frame1.pack();
                frame1.setLocation(100, 100);
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IsThereEDT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(Frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Hello in frame 2");
                frame2.add(label2);
                frame2.pack();
                frame2.setLocation(200, 200);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                isThereReallyEDT();
            }
        });
    }

    private void isThereReallyEDT() {
        dateRun = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println("                         Time at : " + sdf.format(dateRun));
        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            System.out.println("EventQueue.isDispatchThread");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There isn't Live EventQueue.isDispatchThread, why any reason for that ");
        }
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            System.out.println("SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There isn't Live SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread, why any reason for that ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IsThereEDT isdt = new IsThereEDT();
    }
}

abstract class AccurateScheduledRunnable implements Runnable {

    private ScheduledFuture<?> thisThreadsMonitor;

    public void setThreadMonitor(ScheduledFuture<?> monitor) {
        this.thisThreadsMonitor = monitor;
    }

    protected long getExecutionTime() {
        long delay = -1 * thisThreadsMonitor.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return delay;
    }
}
```

- in the case that Swing JComponent is invoked and visible out of EDT returns minimum Bounds returned from Native OS, but your JPopuMenu Container returns larger area, then there are

a) your code doesn't add JMenuItem(s)

b) your code doesn't add JComponent(s)

c) maybe there are added Custom Component, then nobody knows